# Remove old AndroidStudio Cache folders - OSX

Tags: android, macos, caching

Hi I notice that I have large folders <1Gb from AndroidStudio on Libraries/Cache OSX 10.9

The folders are:

- AndroidStudio
- AndroidStudio1.3
- AndroidStudioBeta
- AndroidStudioPreview1.3
- AndroidStudioPreview1.4

I'm using AndroidStudio 1.4 beta 4 currently

Can I safe delete some of these cache folders? Do you know what would be the proper manner to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's safe generally,

The cache in /System/Library/Caches is useful for system but the cache in ~/Library/Caches are not that useful.

Deleting everything at once is not recommended. But if you want to delete specific file remove it manually

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? Why shouldn't I just delete everything in the 'caches' folder of an Android Studio version I'm not using anymore?

Answer (score 5):

It does not need this. You just delete the cache once on the new version. Of course, 
if you do not see it, there's no problem.

Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.