# Color coding error and truncated file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, color-coding

I encountered a strange problem with my Android Studio while I'm working on my Flutter project.

Look at the screen shot below:
[image]

Notice how the word "final" only partially colored? And there are other keywords that are partially colored.
Not just that, there are also color spilled from one keyword to another. For example the "buffer" word (which is a variable) and ".asInt32List" the purple color spilled.

Moreover, the file is truncated at the bottom as follows:

[image]

Actually there are more text after the last line that appear here. We can see it if we use VisualStudio.

I'm using MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave ver. 10.14.6
and Android Studio 3.5.3
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on November 15, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6

Dart Plugin v191.8593
Flutter Plugin v43.0.1

The file that I'm trying to open is a .dart file and it is for a Flutter project. Its also probably necessary to note that all the other dart files doesn't have this problem and I never had this kind of problem before.

So anyone has an answer to this kind of error?
Is there any other information that I need to include in this question?

Thank you !

Comment: are you install dart and flutter plugins ?

Comment: Yes I have installed all the plugins. As I have said the other dart files doesn't have this problem.@veneno

Comment: try remove android studio cache see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185130/remove-old-androidstudio-cache-folders-osx)

Comment: Its working. thanks!! I removed the folders:
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.5/caches
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.5/framework

Then just restart Android Studio then it works

Comment: ok that`s sound good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I did these steps:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Remove the folders: 
   ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.5/caches 
   ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.5/framework
3. Then just restart Android Studio

Then it works!!

Thanks @veneno for the pointer!