# Android Studio global search is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I have been using Android Studio 4.2.1 on Mac for the past 2 months, and I have been NOT able to use the global search feature which is available by clicking the top-right magnifying glass icon. If I search for anything inside my project from there, I always get "Nothing Found" which makes the tool completely useless.

I have also tried to invalidate caches and restart but made no difference.

Any ideas why that's happening and how to make it work?

Comment: Is your project indexed or had problems?

Comment: Please try to [manually remove cache folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185130/remove-old-androidstudio-cache-folders-osx)

Comment: My project hasn't any problems and I see it being indexed if I make a clean-rebuilt or invalidate caches and restart. But the problem persists. I am unable to search anything inside my project, no matter what I search for. I can find only stuff outside my project.

Comment: To delete caches manually, I looked inside the /System/Library/Caches and ~/Library/Caches/ and couldn't find anything related to Android Studio. Ideas??!!

Comment: @FabrizioFerrari open "SDK Manager > Keymap" in Keymap top-right search box write find "find". In that look for "find in all files" and add one unique shortcut key. look here "https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Mnb.png" . Same way for "search everywhere" same action of magnifier. look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHepS.png

Comment: Uninstall. Then reinstall through "jetbrains toolbox". And shortcut for that feature is Shift+Shift

Comment: Thank you, guys. @pratikvekariya the "Find files..." works just fine for me! Thank you! The "search everywhere" still doesn't look inside my files for some reason. To jemshit Do you mean to uninstall the whole Android Studio? And if so, how would I install with "jetbrains toolbox" as you mentioned?

Comment: @FabrizioFerrari no no no, no need to uninstall android studio. See attached screenshot, just add one unique keyboard shortcut, it will be easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed filter in settings(icon in the popup's top right corner):
[image]

Also, make sure that "all" tab is selected in the left corner.

Comment: No, everything is selected like in your screenshot. Thanks though!

Comment: Anyone else helping with this? Am I the only one having this problem?